# Suppress output of join (KStream,KStream) until JoinWindow is exceeded

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using the KStreams-API for java. I'm trying to join search queries with resulting clicks on the result set. One Query can result in 0 to n clicks. The clicks and the queries are logged in a topic each and can be joined through a request id. When I join them the joined pair is first empty in the part with the click information. (Obviously, because it takes time until a click happens). I'm outputting the records into cassandra to perform an aggregation on them after on (I know I'm not a good boy). Anyway, I don't want to have an "empty join" first with every query, I only want the results after the JoinWindow is exceeded. So is there a way to suppress the output of the Join until the end of the window?

That's the (Kotlin) code of the join:

```
// Consuming the query log topic with message key = request_id
val queryLogs = streamBuilder.stream("query_logs",
            Consumed.with(stringSerdes, querySerdes))

// Consuming the click log topic with message key = request_id
val clickLogs = streamBuilder.stream("click_logs",
            Consumed.with(stringSerdes, clickSerdes))

// Joining the click and the query log on request id to get the information which queries resulted in which clicks
val outerJoin = queryLogs.outerJoin(clickLogs, QueryClickJoiner(),
            JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(30)),
            Joined.with(stringSerdes, clickSerdes, querySerdes))
outerJoin.to("joined_clicks", Produced.with(stringSerdes,queryClickSerdes!!))
```

The resulting 'query-click' will have a field for the query_log and a list of result clicks. I only want the result after the 30 minutes of the join window are over and not every update when a click is joined with a query.

Kind regards

Comment: Please provide a code example and output you have so far to make it easier to help out

Comment: It seems you use a left or outer join? Why not using inner-join?

Comment: Thanks so far. I update the post and added some code. I'm not using inner-join because I also want to capture queries for which there where no clicks. Left-join would be the correct join to use (in terms of SQL joins) but in Kafka left joins are a bit different. As far as I know they would need a click to happen before the query was logged (which is obviously not what I need). But maybe I'm wrong with that? Either way it doesn't fix the issue with the constant updates though.